# XMLHTTPRequest Returning Bad Request (400) - "Require Param: grant_type"

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

new to this side of things and can't seem to find the proper syntax. In the POST request payload, I need to include "grant_type=client_credentials" according to the service I'm trying to access. However, I can't find the JavaScript syntax to include the username and password in the request payload. Here is what I have so far (I have removed my key and secret for obvious reasons):

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var path="https://ops.epo.org/3.1/auth/accesstoken";
    request.onreadystatechange=state_change;

    var encodedData = window.btoa(Key:Secret"); //encode consumer key and secret key

    document.write(encodedData);

    request.open("POST", path, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", encodedData);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    request.send(null);

    function state_change() {
        if (request.readyState == "4") //Request finished and response is ready
        {
            if (request.status == "200") {


   alert("Success");
        }
        else {
            alert("Problem retrieving data");
            console.log(this.responseXML);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, been stuck on this for the last few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to remove null from the send payload and replace with 'grant_type=client_credentials'.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var path="https://ops.epo.org/3.1/auth/accesstoken";
request.onreadystatechange=state_change;

var encodedData = window.btoa("Key:secret"); //encode consumer key and secret key

request.open("POST", path, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", encodedData);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.send('grant_type=client_credentials');

function state_change() {
    if (request.readyState == "4") //Request finished and response is ready
    {
        if (request.status == "200") {
            alert("Success");
            document.write(request.responseText);;

        }
        else {
            alert("Problem retrieving data");
            console.log(this.responseXML);
        }
    }
}
```